# Sci fi short story, enemy weapons made the population deaf

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story at least thirty years ago, an anthology in the UK but the story was set in the US.

A grandmother is struggling to raise her grandson, I think the parents are dead. There is an ongoing war with (I think) Russia. Nothing atomic is mentioned IIRC, instead some futuristic weapons are being deployed.

The problems are caused because a weapon used a while ago  has rendered the population deaf. The woman is continually waving a sign saying NO at this kid to try and get him to behave, she gets him to school. There are despairing teachers trying to instil some learning into these kids , a real problem with both sides being deaf.

Mention is made in the newsheets of another enemy weapon that can cause the body's molecules to separate, causing rapid death, this is characterized by people suddenly growing to giant size and doing a parody of a dance as the weapon destroys them.

I think the downbeat short story ends with her and the kid in the street outside her house, they are suddenly dancing and getting rapidly bigger, surrounded by their neighbours doing the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a future war, an old lady is trying to raise a boy but one of the weapons has made everyone deaf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207310/in-a-future-war-an-old-lady-is-trying-to-raise-a-boy-but-one-of-the-weapons-has)

Comment: @Michael Stewart yep, that's definitely it. I searched through here but I was using 'hearing bomb' as my search term and that didn't pop up